# Pandas - Subtract min date from max date for each group

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I want to add a column that is a result of subtraction of min date from max date for each customer_id to this table

**Input:**

```
action_date customer_id
 2017-08-15       1
 2017-08-21       1
 2017-08-21       1
 2017-09-02       1
 2017-08-28       2
 2017-09-29       2
 2017-10-15       3   
 2017-10-30       3
 2017-12-05       3
```

And get this table

**Output:**

```
action_date customer_id    diff
 2017-08-15       1         18
 2017-08-21       1         18
 2017-08-21       1         18
 2017-09-02       1         18
 2017-08-28       2         32
 2017-09-29       2         32
 2017-10-15       3         51
 2017-10-30       3         51
 2017-12-05       3         51
```

I tried this code, but it puts lots of NaN's

```
group = df.groupby(by='customer_id')
df['diff'] = (group['action_date'].max() - group['action_date'].min()).dt.days
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

you can use [`transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html) method:

```
In [23]: df['diff'] = df.groupby('customer_id') \
                        ['action_date'] \
                        .transform(lambda x: (x.max()-x.min()).days)

In [24]: df
Out[24]:
  action_date  customer_id  diff
0  2017-08-15            1    18
1  2017-08-21            1    18
2  2017-08-21            1    18
3  2017-09-02            1    18
4  2017-08-28            2    32
5  2017-09-29            2    32
6  2017-10-15            3    51
7  2017-10-30            3    51
8  2017-12-05            3    51
```

Comment: Thanks! You are awesome :)

Comment: how do you do this where you want to do the subtraction, but on different a column, but use the min and max date.  (say, you have something called customer_spend_amount or something, and you want the date based subtract on the first and latest customer_spend_amount) ?

Comment: If I understand correclty, something like this (based on MaxU- Answer):  `df['diff'] = df.groupby('customer_id')['action_date'].transform(lambda x: (x - x.min()))`